# How do I select records with max from id column if two of three other fields are identical

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have a table that stores costs for consumables.

```
consumable_cost_id  consumable_type_id  from_date   cost
1                   1                   01/01/2000  £10.95
2                   2                   01/01/2000  £5.95
3                   3                   01/01/2000  £1.98
24                  3                   01/11/2013  £2.98
27                  3                   22/11/2013  £3.98
33                  3                   22/11/2013  £4.98
34                  3                   22/11/2013  £5.98
35                  3                   22/11/2013  £6.98
```

If the same consumable is updated more than once on the same day I would like to select only the row where the consumable_cost_id is biggest on that day.  Desired output would be:

```
consumable_cost_id  consumable_type_id  from_date   cost
1                   1                   01/01/2000  £10.95
2                   2                   01/01/2000  £5.95
3                   3                   01/01/2000  £1.98
24                  3                   01/11/2013  £2.98
35                  3                   22/11/2013  £6.98
```

Edit:

Here is my attempt (adapted from another post I found on here):

```
SELECT cc.* 
FROM 
    consumable_costs cc 
    INNER JOIN 
    ( 
        SELECT 
            from_date, 
            MAX(consumable_cost_id) AS MaxCcId 
        FROM consumable_costs 
        GROUP BY from_date 
    ) groupedcc 
        ON cc.from_date = groupedcc.from_date 
            AND cc.consumable_cost_id = groupedcc.MaxCcId
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I adapted this from a post I found on here.<br>SELECT cc.*
FROM consumable_costs cc
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT from_date, MAX(consumable_cost_id) AS MaxCcId
    FROM consumable_costs
    GROUP BY from_date
    ) groupedcc ON cc.from_date = groupedcc.from_date AND cc.consumable_cost_id = groupedcc.MaxCcId

Comment: Please click the "edit" link at the bottom of your question and append new information that way. Don't make people wade through the comments to try and figure out what you've done.

Comment: Sorry, not used the site to ask a question before! Will-do in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close. This seems to work for me:

```sql
SELECT cc.*
FROM 
    consumable_cost AS cc
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            Max(consumable_cost_id) AS max_id, 
            consumable_type_id,
            from_date
        FROM consumable_cost
        GROUP BY consumable_type_id, from_date
    ) AS m
        ON cc.consumable_cost_id = m.max_id
```

Comment: That's brilliant!! Been struggling with this all day.  Thanks Gord.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM consumable_cost 
GROUP by consumable_type_id, from_date
ORDER BY cost DESC;
```

Comment: This should give an error along the lines of "Not a group function"

Comment: Access doesn't work that way: "Cannot group on fields selected with '*'."

Comment: Yeah that's what I got.  Tried selecting all 4 fields by name and that didn't work either. error 'You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'consumable_cost_id' as part of an aggregate function.'

Comment: Didn't know it was for Access. Gord's query should work fine then.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming consumable_cost_id is unique.

```
SELECT * FROM T t1
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT t2.consumable_type_id, t2.from_date FROM T t2
    GROUP by t2.consumable_type_id, t2.from_date
    HAVING MAX(t2.consumable_cost_id) = t1.consumable_cost_id);
```

Because of comment that this was returning an incorrect result, I created a test-query for Oracle that proves that this query works. As I said, it's for Oracle, but there is really no reason why this should not work in MS Access. The only Oracle specific I used here is the `FROM DUAL` to generate the virtual data.

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT 1 AS consumable_cost_id,1 AS consumable_type_id, TO_DATE('01/01/2000','DD/MM/YYYY') AS FROM_DATE, '£10.95' AS COST FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,2,TO_DATE('01/01/2000','DD/MM/YYYY'),'£5.95' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,3,TO_DATE('01/01/2000','DD/MM/YYYY'),'£1.98' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 24,3,TO_DATE('01/11/2013','DD/MM/YYYY'),'£1.98' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 27,3,TO_DATE('22/11/2013','DD/MM/YYYY'),'£1.98' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 33,3,TO_DATE('22/11/2013','DD/MM/YYYY'),'£1.98' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 34,3,TO_DATE('22/11/2013','DD/MM/YYYY'),'£1.98' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 35,3,TO_DATE('22/11/2013','DD/MM/YYYY'),'£1.98' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT * FROM T t1
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT t2.consumable_type_id, t2.from_date FROM T t2
    GROUP by t2.consumable_type_id, t2.from_date
    HAVING MAX(t2.consumable_cost_id) = t1.consumable_cost_id);
```

Result:

```
1    1   01-JAN-00   £10.95
2    2   01-JAN-00   £5.95
3    3   01-JAN-00   £1.98
24   3   01-NOV-13   £1.98
35   3   22-NOV-13   £1.98
```

Comment: He didn't specify Max(cost), he specified Max(consumable_cost_id).

Comment: This incorrectly returns, assuming t1.cost_consumable_cost_id should read t1.consumable_cost_id, and T represents table 'consumable_costs', consumable_cost_id of 33 and cost 4.98 for the 22/11/2013.

Comment: You might want to double check that. I'm pretty sure this query is correct.

Comment: double-checked and it is still returning consumable_cost_id 33 with cost £4.98, and not consumable_cost_id 35 (the maximum for that date) with associated cost £6.98

Comment: I created a test-case, which I added to my answer, which confirms that the query is indeed correct. So there must be another issue with how you adapted it to your schema.